# How to use ET GeoWizard tools or Xtools Pro in ModelBuilder or Python to automate processing?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, modelbuilder, geoprocessing, et-geowizards

Is it possible to use ET GeoWizard or XTools Pro tools in automation of mapping in either in ModelBuilder or Python?

Comment: Nice to know, that's what I was trying to figure out before purchese a ET Geowizard's license. Thanks

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, I believe it is possible to use both in Python scripts. XTools has some samples in your install directory (mine is an older version and is installed at C:\Program Files (x86)\DataEast\XToolsPro 7.1\Scripts). You need to [import the Toolbox](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/ImportToolbox/000v00000046000000/). Here is an example (assuming you are on ArcGIS 10 and using arcpy, otherwise use the geoprocessor):

```
arcpy.ImportToolbox('path_to\XTools Pro.tbx')
arcpy.XToolsPro_<tool_name>(args)
```

It's been a while since I used ET Geowizards tools in a script, but here is how I'm betting that works (along the same lines as with XTools):

```
arcpy.ImportToolbox('path_to\ET GeoWizards.tbx')
arcpy.ET_GP<tool_name>(args)
```

Comment: I do not know about XTools, but for ET ..., assuming that you have registered (pro) version- otherwise you can not use it in model builder or Python. You can add toolbox from ET installation folder to your toolbox bar, open Model Builder and drag it, if you want it in Python, then you export your model from Model Builder to Python script. In this way your syntax is always correct. You can also check help in ET, similarly to ESRI products there are examples of code for scripting.

Comment: ET Geowizards works the same as Chad shows for XTools - as long as licenced.

Comment: @MattPira - If this solved your problem, please mark this as answered to close out the question. Thanks.

Comment: @MattPira - On this answer, below the vote count and up/downvote buttons, check the grey arrow to make it green, and that marks a question as answered.